# AWS Elb backend authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, aws-elb

I was reading about backend authentication option in AWS ELB.
What it mentions is there is a instance public key (.pem encoded) to be configured in ELB.

What I could not understand is what is this key or certificate?

Since it is optional will the traffic will still be encrypted between ELB and EC2 instances if port `443` is used.

There is no details mentioned on how to actually do this.
Basically I want end to end encryption from user to elb and elb to ec2.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what this is saying is that if you what **encryption in transit** for the entire journey  you will need to install an SSL certificate on your EC2 instance. The journey will look like the below.

```
client ---(HTTPS)--> load balancer ---(HTTPS)--> EC2 host
```

You will need to either purchase an SSL, or use a free option such as [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) on your server.

Then once you have this you will need to configure for the web server software you are running. Below are some instructions for common web servers:

- [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)
- [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)
- [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis)
- [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Ensure that your target group is configured for HTTPS port 443 traffic, to have the load balancer forward requests to HTTPS on your backend.

If the load balancer to EC2 host is not encrypted (plain HTTP) the clients traffic to load balancer will still be encrypted, but after this will be forward in HTTP.

Comment: This certificate has to be a certificate from Certificate Authority or it can be a self signed certificate .?<br/> we can have all the ec2 instance have the same certificate and have it burned in the AMI so that all the future instances have it configured ?

Comment: From previous experience I can confirm it will work with a self-signed SSL

Comment: I though backend authentication is for validating the web servers on elb .

Comment: Your question mentions authentication and encryption which are unrelated in an ALB sense. If you have the SSL then this provides encryption between the load balancer and nodes (no authentication process). There is also ALB [authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html) but this is to authenticate users before they can receive ALB traffic :)